# Auto-updating tables which base its data from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

If I have data such like this in one sheet

```
value | key
============
apple |  1
pear  |  1
orange|  2
cat   |  2
dog   |  3
```

and I want to use this generate separate tables in another that present this data as such

```
|  1   |
========
|apple | 
|pear  | 

|  2   | 
========
|orange| 
|cat   |

|  3   | 
========
|dog   |
```

and if I updated the data(eg cat : 2  -> cat : 3) the tables will automatically update themselves

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({"♥"&QUERY(QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A", 0), 
 "select Col1 offset 1", 0), IF(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)<>"", "♥"&QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A limit 0", 0), )})
 ,,999^99))&"♥♦",,999^99), "♥♦"))))
```

[image: 0]